# On blur/focus events, how can you get blur not to fire if the next focus is in the same parent element?

Tags: javascript, html

I think the question is pretty straight forward. The code is below.

```
<button onclick="toggleMenu()">Show Menu</button>

<div id="parent" class="hidden">
    <input type="text"></input>
    <input type="text"></input>
    <input type="text"></input>
</div>

<script>

    let parent = document.getElementById('parent');

    parent.addEventListener('focus', function () {
        // show parent
    });

    parent.addEventListener('blur', function () {
        // hide parent
    });

</script>
```

The idea is that `parent` is something like a hamburger menu. It has an outside element where you can toggle the visible state of it. For accessibility reasons, I'd like to understand how I can make it `visible` or `showing` based on the focus of the input fields.

Is this at all possible?

The code above works but I'm concerned about `onblur()` and `onfocus()` being called EVERY time the user changes input fields.

Comment: Add event listener to input field not on div

Comment: Thanks for the help! That's not quite what I'm looking for though. The focus/blur event will still fire on the `parent` here because the event propagates up the DOM. If you're talking about adding it to only the first and last input field that could work but I'm looking for a more scale-able approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can watch the mousedown or touchstart event on parent. If I remember it correctly, you can check if target element contained in parent, and if so, prevent event to stop next events, and because of that no blur would happen.

The main disadvantage of that behavior is that the action triggered not on click event, and user can't just cancel it moving cursor away from the menu item holding the mouse button.

Answer (score 1):

Add some delay to the action you want to perform on the blur and constraint the action according to a flag which you set on the focus:

```
let parent = document.getElementById('parent');
let focused = false;

parent.addEventListener('focus', function () {
    focused = true;
    console.log('show');
}, true);

parent.addEventListener('blur', function () {
    focused = false; // reset the flag
    setTimeout(function () {
        if (focused) return; // cancel if another input focused after the blur
        console.log('hide');
    }, 100);
}, true);
```